# I'm working with Filament V2 in Laravel and trying to integrate a stored procedure into it. How to properly execute a stored procedure in filament V2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

This is the stored procedure that i want to execute:

CREATE PROCEDURE `inputTransaction`(
IN `transaction_type` VARCHAR(255),
IN `id_product` INT,
IN `purchase_quantity` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE price_unit BIGINT;
DECLARE total_price BIGINT;

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT product_price INTO price_unit FROM products WHERE id = id_product;

IF price_unit IS NOT NULL THEN
    
    SET total_price = purchase_quantity * price_unit;

    INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_type, date, total_transaction)
    VALUES (transaction_type, NOW(), total_price);

    SET @id_transaction = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO detail_transactions (id_transaction, id_product, purchase_quantity, price_unit, total, date)
    VALUES (@id_transaction, id_product, purchase_quantity, price_unit, total_price, NOW());

    -- Commit transaksi
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    -- IF id_product not found, rollback transaction
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

END

And by the way, i'm using laragon as my database.

I've tried various solution from the internet, but it's still not working.